# Random uninterruptible sleep processes / IO spikes

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, arch-linux, luks

Starting last week, I've been having a problem where various processes will go into the uninterruptible sleep state for about 5-10 minutes at a time and then unblock themselves like nothing ever happened. It might happen a few times an hour or only a few times a day.

I'm running Arch with kernel 4.20.3-arch1-1-ARCH and have two hard drives in a RAID 1 array with the filesystem encrypted with LUKS.

Running `ps`, I see that the following processes are commonly in uninterruptible sleep during these IO spikes:

```
md125_raid1
dmcrypt_write/2
jbd2/dm-1-8
kworker/u16:2+flush-253:1
```

The output from `iostat` during a spike:

```
Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
sda              0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc              0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb              0.00    1.50      0.00      3.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    1.67   0.00     0.00     2.00   0.00   0.00
sdd              0.00    1.50      0.00      3.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    2.67   0.00     0.00     2.00   0.00   0.00
md127            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
md126            0.00    0.50      0.00      2.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     4.00   0.00   0.00
md125            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
sde              0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
sdf              0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
md124            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0             0.00    0.50      0.00      2.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00   26.00   0.01     0.00     4.00  26.00   1.30
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00  51.00     0.00     0.00   0.00 100.00
dm-2             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop0            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
```

- `dm-1` always hits 100% utilization.
- There is no relevant info in the kernel log.
- Both disks are ~6 months old and pass a SMART self-test.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. It doesn't seem like it's any particular program that's causing this, but rather something in the kernel or the RAID/LUKS code. Is there anything else I can do to further debug what is causing this problem?

Comment: Not sure if this is related: I've had a similar problem for quite some time now (though no RAID). Dropping caches with `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` unblocks the processes and improves I/O throughput, though they may block again after some time. I haven't found out the reason for this.

Comment: @dirkt Awesome, that unblocks it for me too. I have to keep a window open running `/bin/sh` as root to run it because otherwise zsh will block on IO when trying to run a command. It doesn't solve the problem, but at least it can unblock it so the system is usable without waiting 10 minutes. Thank you!

Comment: If you find out the actual root problem of this, I'd be very much interested in it.